# Opening a new tab, but should function as a back button with saved search

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where you can search rates using location and dates. Once you get to the confirmation page I have a link to go back and select a different rate. By using `history.go(-2)` I can go back to the rates page fine. But I were to right click open or wheel click, it just goes to the home page, because the search criteria is not saved.
How do I go about fixing this?

`<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-2)"><u>select a different rate</u></a>`

Comment: depending on how you pass parameters from a page to another you can make it as a form with hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser history cannot be inherited by a new tab, as far as I know.

You can, however, pass the previous page URL to the new page as a URL parameter, for example:

> domain.com/newPage?oldPage=http%3A%2F%2Foldpage.com

You can then modify the browser history when the new page loads, adding the previous page. See [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I ended up using href=document.referrer. That seems to be doing the trick!